# How can I use SQL to break comma-separated values into new rows - Zoho SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following dataset:

| Name | Qualities |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | Authentic,Cool,Young |
| Bob | Serious,Old,Authentic |
| Carl | Cool,Athletic,Hardworker |

I need to use SQL to turn this dataset into the following:

| Name | Qualities |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | Authentic |
| Adam | Cool |
| Adam | Young |
| Bob | Serious |
| Bob | Old |
| Bob | Authentic |
| Carl | Cool |
| Carl | Athletic |

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: @Marco, do you seriously expect that from newcomers? come on...

Comment: @Nick, please tag your post with the relevant database / SQL engine, e.g., `postgresql`, `mysql`, `sql-server` etc. - **use only one**

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I expect at least some effort, yes. Am I too harsh?

Comment: The OP actually tried to format it nicely, but not all users are familiar with markdown or even aware that markdown is being used in SO posts.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the power of regular expressions over here.

```
    select distinct name,regexp_substr(qualities,'[^,]+',1,level) quality
 from <<table_name>> 
   connect BY regexp_substr(qualities, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
order by 1;
```